# Using Pandas to calculate change in values of a date series

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a dataframe containing sales of products. It includes customers account number, transaction date, value + others.

I want to find out if a customers sales are declining and thought if I grouped them together by quarter I could then use pct_change() to work this out but its not working how I expected.

```
+------------+------------+------------+
| SA_ACCOUNT | SA_TRDATE  | SA_TRVALUE |
+------------+------------+------------+
| AAA1       | 2019-01-01 |      65.65 |
| AAA1       | 2019-02-08 |     698.65 |
| AVD2       | 2019-01-05 |      98.28 |
+------------+------------+------------+
```

I have started by grouping by date and account and totalling the value. Then resampling it into quarters, then finally unstacking the dates so they become the column heading. This has presented the data in the format below.

CODE:

```
sales_by_q = new_frame2.groupby(["SA_ACCOUNT","SA_TRDATE"]).sum().reset_index().set_index("SA_TRDATE")[["SA_ACCOUNT","SA_TRVALUE"]].groupby("SA_ACCOUNT").resample("q").sum().unstack().fillna(0)
```

EXAMPLE OUTPUT:

```
    +------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
    | SA_ACCOUNT | 2017-12-31 | 2018-03-31 | 2018-06-30 | 2018-09-30 | 2018-12-31 | 2019-03-31 | 2019-06-30 | 2019-09-30 |
    +------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
    | AA11       |      0.000 |      0.000 |     12.000 |      4.000 |      0.000 |      3.000 |      0.000 |      0.000 |
    | AA99       |      0.000 |      3.000 |      0.000 |      0.000 |      0.000 |      0.000 |      0.000 |      0.000 |
    | AAA1       |    171.000 |    407.000 |     78.000 |     23.000 |     23.000 |     20.000 |     70.000 |    208.000 |
    | AAC1       |      0.000 |      0.000 |      0.000 |     64.000 |     10.000 |      5.000 |     21.000 |      6.000 |
    +------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

I wan't to now know if these values are decreasing over time (if the customer is spending less or not) but can't seem to find the best way to acomplish this.

I then thought I could work out the coef of a regression line and used scikitlearn. But its still not exactly what I was after, not every customer will order quarterly, some lots more, some a lot less. Also if someone has performed porly in the middle quarters but well at the beginning and end quarters, the coeff is still majorly negative.

```
from sklearn import linear_model

    def calc_vert(x):
        df = pd.DataFrame(x).reset_index()
        x_vals = np.arange(0,df[df.columns[0]].count()).reshape(-1, 1)
        y_vals = df[df.columns[1]]
        regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
        regr.fit (x_vals, y_vals)
        return regr.coef_

    test1["coeff"] = test1.apply(lambda x: calc_vert(x),axis = 1)
```

Any suggestions? On a better way to tackle this?

Comment: You have to define what you want. What does it mean that 'sales are declining'? Over what time period? Are you interested in absolute or percentage drops, that is, is someone spending $900 instead of $1000 as bad of a drop as $0 instead of $100, or is the latter worse? Are you interested in all drops or only significant ones? Etc, etc.

Comment: I'm interested in ranking people by biggest decline in sales over the last 2 years. 1000 to 900 isnt as bad as 100 to 0 if the latter customer was always spending 100 to begin with.